# situations where an error will be caught by using unbounded wildcards, but will only be flagged as a warning if you use raw type

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, raw-types

Below is a quote on comparison between`unbounded wildcard types` vs `raw types`, from `Java generics and collection` by  Maurice Naftalin and Philip Wadler.

> We recommend using unbounded wildcard types in preference to raw types
>   because they provide stronger static typing guarantees; many mistakes
>   that are caught as an error when you use unbounded wildcards will only
>   be flagged as a warning if you use raw types.

But the book doesn't provide an code example to explain the situation. I was wondering if someone could add to the explanation by providing an code example?

Comment: There's an example in the answer to the question I've linked as duplicate.

Comment: I don’t think the suggested post answers this question. It certainly adds relevant details, but it does not specifically answers the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could adapt some of the examples of that same chapter to reproduce a case of this.

For example, consider the following generic class:

```
class Node<E> {
   private E value;
   @Override public String toString(){ return value.toString(); }
}
```

Now, imagine that you write the following piece of code, which is wrong:

```
Object o = new Node<Integer>(10);
Node<String> node = new Node<>("Hello");
if(o instanceof Node) {
  Node other = (Node) o;
  other.value = node.value; //Uh oh! Warning
}
System.out.println(node); //Hello
System.out.println(other); //Hello - WTH!
```

If you try to compile this, you would only get a warning, but it would still compile just fine:

```
javac -Xlint:unchecked Node.java

Node.java:21: warning: [unchecked] unchecked assignment to variable value as member of raw type Node
            other.value = node.value;
                 ^
1 warning
```

However, if you change the code to use unbounded wildcards:

```
Object o = new Node<Integer>(10);
Node<String> node = new Node<>("Hello");
if(o instanceof Node<?>) {
  Node<?> other = (Node<?>) o;
  other.value = node.value; //Uh oh! Compiler error
}
```

Now you would get the following error when compiling:

```
javac -Xlint:unchecked Node.java

Node.java:21: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to CAP#1
            other.value = node.value;
                              ^
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
1 error
```

So, as you can see the unbounded wildcard offers better type checking guarantees than the raw type.